# What does it mean if an RMSE has a value far beyond 1?

Tags: statistics, biometrics

If you find RMSE=11 at a sample of 5000, what does that mean ? The data ranges from 63 to 180.

Comment: what you are finding RMSE (root mean squared error) for? RMSE could be more that 1. that's just mean that your model couldn't find a solution or (optimized very well).

Comment: It means that the squared root of squared differences between your predictions and observed values is 11. Naturally lower values indicate a better fit of your model.